# Nicetabular merges blocks

Tags: nicematrix, nicetabular

I have a table in nicetabular, which has one specific problem: the columns are somehow merged?

```
\begin{NiceTabular}[]{c | c | *{4}S[table-format=3.2] | *{4}S[table-format=3.2]}  
& & \Block{1-4}{Shoo}  &  \Block{1-4}{Papapapapa} \\ 
\toprule  
\Block{1-2}{Qualitative Comparison} & \Block{1-2}{A}  & \Block{1-2}{B}  &  \Block{1-2}{C} &  \Block{1-2}{D} &  \\ 
\toprule  
\Block{1-2}{Direct effect } & \Block{1-2}{$\nearrow$} & \Block{1-2}{$\nearrow$} & \Block{1-2}{-} &  \Block{1-2}{-} \\ 
$\%$\textbf{ foo} & \textbf{bar} &  $\mu$=0.025 & $\mu$=0.05 \\ \toprule 
a & b &  -0.9 &  -1.7 &  -0.4 &  -1.7 &  -1.6 &  -1.7 &  -1.7 &  -1.7 \\ 
\bottomrule\end{NiceTabular}
```

\

There are 10 columns, and the first row is supposed to have two empty cells, and two cells that each span 4 columns.
The Second row is supposed to have 5 cells that each span two columns.
Instead, these columns are somehow overlapping/merging into each other, and only take up the first 6 columns -- the last row contains one element in each column and therefore should help span up the entire table.

If I add additional `&` inbetween the columns, I can get the layout that I want, but this cant be the correct approach, can it?

```
\begin{NiceTabular}[]{c | c | *{4}S[table-format=3.2] | *{4}S[table-format=3.2]}  
& & \Block{1-4}{Shock} & & & &  \Block{1-4}{Parameter} \\ 
\toprule  
\Block{1-2}{Qualitative Comparison}& & \Block{1-2}{A}  & & \Block{1-2}{B} &  &  \Block{1-2}{C} & &  \Block{1-2}{D} &  \\ 
\toprule  
\Block{1-2}{Direct effect } & & \Block{1-2}{$\nearrow$} & & \Block{1-2}{$\nearrow$} & & \Block{1-2}{-} & & \Block{1-2}{-} \\ 
$\%$\textbf{ foo} & \textbf{bar} &  $\mu$=0.025 & $\mu$=0.05 \\ \toprule 
a & b &  -0.9 &  -1.7 &  -0.4 &  -1.7 &  -1.6 &  -1.7 &  -1.7 &  -1.7 \\ 
\bottomrule\end{NiceTabular} 
\\
```

Comment: You should provide a complete MWE, that is to say a compilable file beginning with `\documentclass` and  ending with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of the command `\Block` is not the same as the syntax of `\multicolumn`. With `\Block`, you *must* put the ampersands (`&`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}[]{c | c | *{4}S[table-format=3.2] | *{4}S[table-format=3.2]}  
& & \Block{1-4}{Shock} & & & &  \Block{1-4}{Parameter} \\ 
\toprule  
\Block{1-2}{Qualitative\\ Comparison}& & \Block{1-2}{A}  & & \Block{1-2}{B} &  &  \Block{1-2}{C} & &  \Block{1-2}{D} &  \\ 
\toprule  
\Block{1-2}{Direct effect } & & \Block{1-2}{$\nearrow$} & & \Block{1-2}{$\nearrow$} & & \Block{1-2}{-} & & \Block{1-2}{-} \\ 
$\%$\textbf{ foo} & \textbf{bar} &  $\mu$=0.025 & $\mu$=0.05 \\ \toprule 
a & b &  -0.9 &  -1.7 &  -0.4 &  -1.7 &  -1.6 &  -1.7 &  -1.7 &  -1.7 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]